# Render rotated symbols in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, point

I have point with an attribute for each point's 0-360 direction. I need to render these points in Leaflet with arrows pointing in their respective directions. Is there a plugin or code I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker. Alternatively, use a `L.DivIcon` and apply [CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to its contents.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of arrows do you want to display? I have just created a Leaflet plugin which shows the direction and the speed of wind. So if per chance you would like to show wind data, you can use my plugin: https://github.com/JoranBeaufort/Leaflet.windbarb 
Otherwise there is the marker rotate plugin: https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/blob/master/examples/marker-rotate.html which might be of help to you.

Cheers